# What's difference between classname.attribute and self.attribute in Python 3.X

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

There are two codes as below:

```
class State:
    country = "China"

    def __init__(self):
    print(State.country)

obj = State()
```

and:

```
class State:
    country = "China"

    def __init__(self):
        print(self.country)

obj = State()
```

They both work well and have output:

```
China
```

But what's different between these two ways?

Thank you

Comment: search for "class attribute vs instance attribute"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.  http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: For the code you presented, **there is no difference**.  If python cannot find an attribute that is being accessed on a certain object (in `object.__dict__`), it will then search in the object's class's attributes(in `object.__class__.__dict__`). This is what is occurring in your case. Generally however, `Class.attribute` accesses the attributes of the _class object_, while `self.attribute` (or `object.attribute) accesses the attributes of _objects of the class_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This article provides details about what's happening here, and how you should handle it.

https://www.toptal.com/python/python-class-attributes-an-overly-thorough-guide

In both cases, the code is accessing the class attribute `State.country`. Since each instance of `State` has access to the class attribue, `self.country` will return the same value as `State.country`--unless you modify it.

If you choose to assign a new value to an instance of `State`, it will not update "the instance's country attribute" because the instance has no country attribute. Instead, it will create an instance attribute called country for that particular instance, and in the future, when you make a call to the instance's country attribute (e.g. `self.country`), the Python interpreter will find the instance attribute **first**, but the class attribute is still there; the interpreter will simply never find it as long as the instance attribute with the same name still exists.

The following demonstrates this:

```
class State:
    country = "China"

    def __init__(self):
        pass # The constructor is unnecessary for this example

s = State()
print(s.country) # Prints "China"
print(State.country) # Prints "China"

s.country = "Japan" # State.country still equals "China", but s.country has been
                    # created and initialized to "Japan"
print(s.country) # Prints "Japan"
print(State.country) # Prints "China"

new_s = State()
print(new_s.country) # Prints "China"

del s.country # Deletes the instance attribute country created for s
print(s.country) # Prints "China"; now that the instance attribute has been 
                 # deleted, the Python interpreter will fail to find s.country
                 # within the instance namespace, and so it will search the
                 # class namespace and it will find the class attribute State.country
```

This all goes to show that you should research the Python conventions for keeping class attribute and instance attributes distinct, and using each only in the appropriate scenarios.

Answer (score -2):

Its class level vs instance level access.

When you do State.country, it access country attribute of all instances of State

But when you do self.country, it will access only the instance's country attribute.

Making class level modifications will be reflected on all instances that have been created from the class, so this should be used very carefully. self should be the default behavior.

Comment: "But when you do self.country, it will access only the instance's country attribute.". Not true in this case.

Comment: `self.country` might access an awful lot of things ... not just any potential `country` "attribute"

Comment: @MadPhysicist Could you elaborate? What is `self.country` accessing here if not the instance's attribute?

Comment: @donkopotamus I'm talking about this particular case. What else is `self.country` accessing here?

Comment: @harpratap In the particular code example given in the question, `self.country` is definitely *not* returning the instance's country attribute.  There is no such attribute defined on the instance so it is returning the value of `country` defined on the type `State` instead.

Comment: @harpratap. The whole point of the class is to provide the template of shared attributes, which is what it is doing here. Any attribute not found in the instance will be taken from the class. Data descriptors and magic methods are always taken from the class, making things like properties possible.

Comment: @harpratap. There is now an answer that explains the issue correctly available.