# Saving a dictionary to a JSON file in python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to save my objects created, stored in the `__objects` class attribute, and I am getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/leuel/PycharmProjects/AirBnB_clone/./test_save_reload_base_model.py", line 2, in <module>
    from models import storage
  File "/home/leuel/PycharmProjects/AirBnB_clone/models/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    storage.reload()
  File "/home/leuel/PycharmProjects/AirBnB_clone/models/engine/file_storage.py", line 32, in reload
    self.__objects = json.load(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

The method that I used to save to the json file:

```
def save(self):
    with open(self.__file_path, "w+") as f:
        json.dump(self.__objects, f)
```

The `__objects` attribute is a class attribute that is a dictionary holding all instances (instances will be stored using a key based on their ids). Why am I getting the error? Initially, the `__objects` will be an empty dictionary

And another question when referencing class attributes, should I use `self` or should I write the class name? If I should write the class name, is it because instances might change the class attribute? I am new to python and JSON, so excuse me if my question is not clear enough.

EDIT: As @Richard Neumann, pointed out, my error comes from json.load(). Here is the code where I called the json.load():

```
    def reload(self):
    if path.isfile(self.__file_path):
        with open(self.__file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            self.__objects = json.load(f)
```

The `reload` method will reload the `__objects` class attribute from a `file.json` file. I did this to recreate instances when I reopen my program

Comment: Why are you using `json.dump` twice in your `save()` method? Did you mean: `json.dump(self.__objects, f)`?

Comment: To reference class attributes you have to use `self` inside the class methods. If they are public and you are calling them outside the class,then use the name of the instance.

Comment: @quamrana I was trying to come up with a solution, because `json.dump(self.__objects, f)` still gives me the same error

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: @CreepyRaccoon: No, you don't have to use `self`, you can use the class name. (And either the name of the instance or, again, the class name outside of methods as you say)

Comment: The error occurs on `json.load()`, not on `json.dump()`. Show us the actual code where the error occurs, i.e. where you invoke `json.load()` as well as the contents of the respective file.

Comment: I see you have included the full error traceback. Is your file empty?

Comment: @quamrana Yes, I mean if there are no instances, the should be empty right?

Comment: Well no. It should be an empty `dict`. ie `{}`

Comment: Can my program do that? or should I manually make the `file.json` to contain an empty `dict`

Comment: for your 2nd question see: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198381/whats-difference-between-classname-attribute-and-self-attribute-in-python-3-x>

Comment: Well, you are already catching `FileNotFoundError`, so why not also catch `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError` also and then execute: `self.__objects = {}`.

Answer (score 1):

you already encoded your dictionary to a valid `JSON` data when you use `json.dumps` but when you try to dump it again with `json.dump`, python gives an error because `json.dumps` expects a valid python dictionary, not a valid JSON Data, and since you're trying to write to a file, use

```py
f.write(json_string)
```

instead of `json.dump`

Comment: This is plain wrong. You can safely `json.dump{,s}` a string: `json.dumps(json.dumps({}))`